# error: '' `createSwitchNavigator` 'is declared here - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stack, react-navigation

Why can't I use `createstacknavigator`?

> error: '' `createSwitchNavigator` 'is declared here.'

I use only `createSwitchNavigator` though you use it a lot.

I cannot see the `createStackNavigatior` page of react-navigation.

Comment: Attach your codebase into this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have to re-install the library. As i can see this [`@react-navigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation) is the package which needs to be installed and then import it like:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

Answer (score 0):

In latest version use it like this,
createStackNavigator and many more library is shifted into a separate package.

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
```